# How to add select dropdown next to length menu in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to add a custom dropdown filter next to the length menu as shown in the picture below

[image]

I tried it with

```
var product = '<select id="product"><option value="consoles">Consoles</option><option value="peripherals">Peripherals</option></select>';

var config = {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/app/get_products",
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
      if($('.dataTables_length').find('#product').length < 1){
          $('.dataTables_length').append(product);
      }
    },
    "fnServerParams" : function ( aoData ) {
        var type = $("#product").val();
        aoData.push({ "name": "type", "value": type });
    },
    "fnServerParams" : function ( aoData ) {
        var type = $("#product").val();
        aoData.push({ "name": "type", "value": type });
    }
  };

$('#table').dataTable(config);
```

the dropdown gets inserted but it has lot of bugs. It's selected value is not persistent and changes on datatable option change or pagination change.

What is the correct way to achieve this?