# How to add Drop-Down list in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data-table similar to http://legacy.datatables.net/index. I wanted to add a Dropdown just next to

> Show 10 Entries

section on the displayed table and then the selected value in drop down should filter on the specific column of the table displayed on the page. How to achieve this ?

Comment: you have to add it in the datatable dom.

Comment: may be it will help you https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541769/how-to-add-select-dropdown-next-to-length-menu-in-datatables

Comment: Thanks. I will try the suggestions.